# How to normalise polynomial coefficients in a fraction?

Tags: matlab, polynomial-math

I have the following code:

```
syms z
Gc=1.582*(1-0.3679*z^-1)/(1+.418*z^-1);
Ghp=.3679*(z^-1)*(1+.718*z^-1)/((1-z^-1)*(1-.3679*z^-1));
T=(Gc*Ghp)/(1+Gc*Ghp);
clipboard('copy', latex(simplifyFraction(T)));
```

Which results in following for `T`:

[image]

How can I normalise coefficients? I.e. I want the z<sup>2</sup> in denominator and z in numerator to have the coefficient of 1. 
Is there any function in Matlab to do so?

Comment: I would say that you need a normalization coefficient, like `b_0`. However, that may not work in case you decide to go for symbols. Then matlab will answer in a fractional numbers and will try to avoid decimals. In case you increase the amount of decimals, the fractions will be longer. Do you have a special reason why you use symbols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the numerator and denominator with `numden`, then get their coefficiens with `coeffs`, normalize the polynomials, and divide again.

```
[n,d] = numden(T);
cn = coeffs(n);
cd = coeffs(d);
T = (n/cn(end))/(d/cd(end));
```

The output of `latex(T)` (note: no `simplifyFraction` now; it would undo things):

[image: output]

If you prefer coefficients in decimal form, use `vpa(T)`: here is `latex(vpa(T))`.

[image: vpa]

---

Of course the above isn't *equal* to your original fraction, since I in effect multiplied it by `cd(end)/cn(end)`. Depending on your purposes, you can either

- keep the constant coefficient `cn(end)/cd(end)` separately in your computation, or
- use `(cn(end)/cd(end))*((n/cn(end))/(d/cd(end)));` to put it back in. Unfortunately, Matlab is too eager to combine the two fractions into one, but you can still see the normalized polynomials.

[image: new image]

Comment: very nice! I hadn't known about numden. One small note: the numerator in the example is multiplied by 2910089, which I don't believe your output accounts for.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer; I expanded my answer. Naturally, after changing both leading coefficients to 1 the fraction could not stay equal to the original.

Comment: @Idisagree Thanks. I am happier with your first notation. How can I ask matlab to evaluate all numerical fractions both in numerator and denominator? i.e. I want my numerator to be z + 0.658

Comment: @Bababarghi `vpa` does that, I added this part to the answer.